# Changing CSS property of an element when hovering another element

Tags: css

I have a `div` called image. It has a CSS-property `visibility:hidden;`. I have another button called button.

What I need is when I hover the button, the image changes to `visibility:visible;`.

Can I do it with CSS or do I have to use JavaScript?

Comment: Java? Maybe Javascript you mean.

Comment: Post a snippet of your code. Also: What have you tried so far?

Comment: JavaSCRIPT. Java and JavaScript are two entirely different things. Presumably you mean the latter. Also, post the relevant HTML for this question.

Comment: You can do it with CSS if your HTML is suitable. Add a sample of your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can do this

as like this

**HTML**

```
<label for="button">Click here</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="button">

  <div class="one">Show my div</div>
```

**Css**

```
label{
background:green;
  padding:10px;
 }
.one{
width:100px;
  display:none;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:20px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
visibility:hidden;

}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .one{
display:block;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/eB4BChw6)

---

**Updated answer**

if you want to **just hover** than check to **this** **[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/0TAAea4f)**

Comment: @Ariel just for you check to this link if you want to just hover that is very simple http://tinkerbin.com/0TAAea4f

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is a javascript / jQuery solution:

```
$(button).hover(function() {
    $('div#image').attr('visibility', 'visible');
}, function() {
    $('div#image').attr('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if the div is a child of the button - which isn't possible.

It's possible if you make it a child of something else (i.e. not a button, do it differently).

However, what browser? All the main ones? Because if you are willing to use only the most modern it's possible by using sibling selectors.

But for mainstream usage you can only do it if the div is a child of the hover element. Note: You can hover anything, it doesn't have to be a button or a link `<a>`. So that's what I would do - make a div element that *looks* like a button, and has a child that you want to change.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a child. For example: `<button>Hover me!</button><div>Toggle visibility</div>` with `div { visibility: hidden; } button:hover + div { visibility: visible; }` which will work in IE7 and all newer browsers. (I'm not sure if I didn't read the part in your answer about "sibling selectors", or if you edited it before I wrote this comment.)

Comment: @thirtydot I did not edit it - you didn't read it. You can clearly see there is no "edit" info on the answer. And for your lack of reading you downvote me?

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything here. You can have a sympathy upvote, your answer doesn't deserve the downvote. I thought you might have edited it because I did see the "live edit notification" on your answer when I was writing my comment. Any edits made within the first five minutes do not show as a new revision.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks. It's possible I fixed a grammatical error or a typo, but I definitely put in the info about sibling selectors from the start.

Answer (score -1):

You need javascript for that. You can use css if your div is parent for the button, but in your case this is not possible
JS

```
function changeVisibility(objID) {
    var el = document.getElementById(objID);
    if(el.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        el.style.visibility = 'visible';
        return true;
    }

    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="box">Something to show</div>
<input type="button" class="button" onmouseover="changeVisibility('box')" value="Change visibility" />
```